# SonarQube LDAP plugin deployed but not "enabled"

Tags: authentication, ldap, sonarqube, sonarqube-ops

SQ 5.6, LDAP plugin 2.0.

I've successfully installed the LDAP plugin and restarted the SQ server. In the log (/opt/sonar/logs/sonar.log) the plugin is apparently deployed, but seemingly no attempt is made to initialize/enable it or connect to the LDAP server.

```
INFO  web[o.s.s.p.ServerPluginRepository] Deploy plugin LDAP / 2.0 / 2910f3981167a70a201ccfae01471dfd26c794b7
.
.
INFO  web[o.s.s.p.RailsAppsDeployer] Deploying app: ldap
```

These are the only mentions of ldap/LDAP in the log.

Relevant part of the conf/sonar.properties file:

```
sonar.security.realm=LDAP
ldap.url=ldap://myldap:389
ldap.user.baseDn=ou=mycompany,ou=People,dc=myurl,dc=com
```

I believe I've verified ldap.url and ldap.user.baseDn via JXplorer (an LDAP browser).

What really puzzles me is that I don't see anything like the following in the logs, which is what I'd expect from the SQ docs:

```
INFO org.sonar.INFO Security realm: LDAP ...
INFO o.s.p.l.LdapContextFactory Test LDAP connection: OK
```

No errors of any kind are noted in the log.

Any idea why SQ is not even apparently trying to kick off LDAP authentication on a restart?

Comment: Once you specify `sonar.security.realm=LDAP` in `sonar.properties` and restart your server then the LDAP Plugin should definitely kick-in and log stuff in the logs. Did you just double-check that the right `sonar.properties` is used ? If needed then share your full startup logs and `sonar.properties`.

Comment: How can I verify that the sonar.properties file I'm editing really is being used (/opt/sonar/conf/sonar.properties)? I am suspicious of this, because changes to it (including putting in a bogus value for sonar.security.realm) elicit no response (i.e. no error or warning message). Administration->System Info indicates my Sonar Home Dir is /opt/sonar. And the active log file is /opt/sonar/logs/sonar.log, so it seems like that is the correct home dir.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I'm running Sonarqube using docker. It did not pick up on changes when I restart the server from the Sonarqube UI. Only after restarting the docker image it could pick up the changed file.

Comment: This was also for me the case and should be the accepted answer!
Although I'm not using docker, restarting the sonarqube via command line did the trick for me.

Answer (score 0):

Well, now it just started working. I don't have an answer as to why though. Maybe something changed with my LDAP server, or there was some latency that needed to be overcome. I didn't change anything on my end that I'm aware of. In any case, thanks to those that responded.